# Infinite House of Pancakes

Tags: c++

Here's a link to the problem in question: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6224486/dashboard#s=p1

Okay, so I got a bit hung up on this problem. Now that the quals are over, does anyone know why this wouldn't work? I've checked against about 50 different cases and haven't been able to find one that doesn't work. Here's my full code below.

Basically, looking for any cases where my algorithm could break.

```
//Includes
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


//Functions
int solve(list<int>);

//Main
int main() {
    int minutes = 0;
    int numTestCases = 0;
    int initNonEmpty = 0;
    char tempChar;
    int tempInt;
    list<int> people;

    //Import Data
    //Get number of Test cases
    ifstream infile;
    infile.clear();
    infile.open("B-small-attempt5.in");

    //get NumTestCases
    infile >> numTestCases;
    int solution[numTestCases];

    //Solve it
    for(int i=0; i<numTestCases; i++){
        //Reset vars
        initNonEmpty=0;
        infile >> initNonEmpty;
        people.clear();

        //Input data
        for(int j=0; j<initNonEmpty; j++){
            infile >> tempInt;
cout << tempInt;
        people.push_back(tempInt);
        }
cout << endl;

        //Solve the set
        people.sort();
        people.reverse();
        tempInt = solve(people);
cout << "Solve returns: " << tempInt << endl << endl;
        solution[i] = tempInt;      
    }

    //Output
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("RealCase6.out");
    for (int i=0; i < numTestCases; i++){
        cout << "Case #" << i+1 << ": " << solution[i] << endl;
        outfile << "Case #" << i+1 << ": " << solution[i] << endl;
    }

}

int solve( list<int> data){
cout << "Starting Solve functions." << endl;
    int tempMax;
    int max =data.front();
    int test=0;

cout << "Max: " << max << endl;

    //Test if base case
    if(max<=3){
cout << "Reached base case." << endl;
        return max;
    }
    else if (max % 2 == 0 ){
cout << "Max is even" << endl;
        tempMax = max/2;
        data.pop_front();
        data.push_back(tempMax);
        data.push_back(tempMax);
        data.sort();
        data.reverse();
        test=solve(data);
        test=test+1;
cout << "test is:" << test << endl;
cout << "max is:" << max << endl;
        if( test<=max){
            return test;
        } else {
            return max;
        }
    }
    else {
cout << "Max is odd" << endl;
        tempMax = max/2;
        data.pop_front();
        data.push_back(tempMax);
        data.push_back(tempMax+1);
        data.sort();
        data.reverse();
        test=solve(data);
        test=test+1;
cout << "test is:" << test << endl;
cout << "max is:" << max << endl;
        if(test<=max){
            return test;
        } else {
            return max;
        }
    }

}
```

And here's my input/output for 6 different cases.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/55wq52lzuygd82s/AABYxJJ7zaeoMhgCmymJcwnAa?dl=0

I'll remove this if this is too early to start asking about the problems. Sorry about eh formatting, but I was trying to get this done quickly.

Edit1: Added Link to problem.

Edit2: Someone else found the error. I only thought to divide things into groups of 2, which gives a case of one person with 9 pancakes, where dividing it into a group of 6 and 3 and then 3 3 3 works best.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? What doesn't work? You cannot seriously believe we will be able to guess what your problem is.

Comment: @vsoftco When I submitted during the qualification round, I was only told that my solution was incorrect. I was hoping that someone else looking at it could point out any stupid errors. As far as I can tell, it should work correctly.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that we know what the "Infinite House of Pancakes" problem is. I, for one, have no clue.

Comment: @KeithThompson Sorry, I'll add a link to the problem in the description.

Comment: In addition to your answer: The top competitor's answer gives non-optimal answers for some cases -- e.g., `7` instead of `6` for the case `2 8 1 8` -- so I think Google's grading is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

This breaks in cases where it's more efficient to divide into non-equivalent stacks. For example, the case

> 1
>   9

where one person has 9 pancakes. Dividing as evenly as possible into groups of 2 gives the solution:

> min 1: `9`
>   min 2: `5 4`
>   min 3: `4 3`
>   min 4: `3 2`
>   min 5: `2 1`
>   min 6: `1 0`
>   min 7: `0 0`

where as dividing unevenly gives the solution

> min 1: `9`
>   min 2: `3 6`
>   min 3: `3 3 3`
>   min 4: `2 2 2`
>   min 5: `1 1 1`
>   min 6: `0 0 0`

which is more efficient.