# codejam 2015 qualification round: Infinite House of Pancakes

Tags: algorithm

The problem description and solutions [after contest analysis](http://www.go-hero.net/jam/15/problems/0/2)

There is one case I can't figure out: If there is one plate, 9 pancakes, that is the test case

```
1
9
```

the "correct answer" is `5`

But how? Here is my "faulty" thinking:

```
9 -> {4, 5} -> {4,3,2} -> {3,2,2,2}
```

So it totals `3 + 3 = 6` minutes, not `5`

Anything obvious that I misunderstood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fail on this one during the competition too because I assumed that the best way was to split things in half (to get the maximum height reduction possible).

But, in viewing your question I can see a way that would do better then halving:

9 -> {6, 3} -> {3, 3, 3}

Two swaps plus three minutes to eat: 5 minutes

Comment: Now I need to take another look at my solution to see if I can fix it to see these cases too.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered here:
[Infinite House of Pancakes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585210/infinite-house-of-pancakes)

Basically this is a case where dividing unevenly will give a better solution, for example:

```
9
3 6
3 3 3
2 2 2
1 1 1
0 0 0
```

Which is better than dividing evenly